# Building Framework as "Generic iOS Device" Causes Use of Undeclared Type in Project Using Framework

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, swift-framework

Basically, as stated in the title, when I build my Cocoa Touch Framework for "Generic iOS Device," it causes "Use of Undeclared Type" compilation errors in my XCode project using the framework. However, when I build the XCode Project for "Generic iOS Device" too, the errors go away.

My question is: How can I build the framework in such a way that it can be used for simulators as well as a generic iOS device?

I was under the impression that building a Cocoa Touch Framework for "Generic iOS Device" would allow it to be used in any build configuration. Is this incorrect?

Is there something that has to be changed in the build settings or schemes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was mistaken, and due to simulators and iPhones having different architectures, you have to compile the framework for each one respectively. However, I was able to create a "fat framework" by following this Medium article: https://medium.com/@hassanahmedkhan/a-noobs-guide-to-creating-a-fat-library-for-ios-bafe8452b84b

This fat framework can be used for both "Generic iOS Device" and the simulator.